# Ubuntu gone after updating Mac OS X

Tags: macos, unix

After installing updates for Mac, rEFInd won't show up when the computer starts, and even if I held down the Option key the disk manager only shows Macintosh HD. I already tried disabling csrutil and also reinstalling rEFInd, none of those work.

When I held down Option-Command-P-R then opened disk utility, it showed both Macintosh HD and disk0s3 (name of my ubuntu partition) but disk0s3 was greyed out.

How do I get into ubuntu again?

Version: Mac OS High Sierra

Ubuntu Version: 16.04 LTS

Comment: Could you add some details on exactly what version of OS and hardware you are using. The more details you provide the easier it is for others to answer your question.

Comment: @TonyWilliams edited, please see!

Comment: Please post the output of the command `diskutil list disk0`

Comment: Instead of editing the question, you can add the solution as an answer yourself and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @NimeshNeema fine

Answer (score 2):

I solved it! My mistake was trying to install another, newer version of rEFInd at first without completely removing my previous rEFInd folder. I then deleted my newly downloaded rEFInd folder then simply installed my old rEFInd version again.